# Unable to capture details

Tags: go

I am using the below github repo.

https://github.com/tooolbox/cybersource-rest-client-go

I wanted to convert data returned in the test code into separate variables in order to use them but i am unable to get the respective values.

the test is also available in main.go in the repo.

```
  created, err := c.Payments.CreatePayment(req)
  log.Printf("\n\n")
  log.Printf("Created: %v\n", created)
  log.Printf("Err: %v\n", err)
```

I am unable to unmarshal the data from the returned values stored in created.

any assistance will be really good, as I am stuck for long time on resolving this.

Comment: *"I am unable to unmarshal the data from the returned values stored in created."* -- Can you share the code where you're trying to "unmarshal" the `created` value? And can you share the error? Or the expected and the actual result?

Comment: Created: [POST /pts/v2/payments/][201] createPaymentCreated  &{Links:0xc0006ae8e0 ClientReferenceInformation:0xc000366480 ErrorInformation:<nil> ID:6260207416076122804004 InstallmentInformation:<nil> IssuerInformation:<nil> OrderInformation:0xc0006ac5e0 PaymentInformation:0xc0006ae960 PointOfSaleInformation:<nil> ProcessingInformation:<nil> ProcessorInformation:0xc000001680 ReconciliationID:6260207416076122804004 Status:AUTHORIZED SubmitTimeUtc:2021-07-11T16:25:41Z}

above is the output i am getting from the data stored in variable created. I wanted separate Links as array.

Comment: Please edit the question and add the details there, as comments they are unreadable.

Comment: That looks like the output of the `log.Printf("Created: %v\n", created)` statement, `log.Printf` is *not* for "unmarshaling" unless by "unmarshaling" you mean logging, in which case there does not seem to be any problem with the code.

Comment: How do I unmarshal created variable the printf shows the output but unable to unmarshal the variable.

Comment: The response from the request is already unmarshaled into the type [`CreatePaymentCreated`](https://github.com/tooolbox/cybersource-rest-client-go/blob/master/client/payments/create_payment_responses.go#L62). It is unclear from you question what further unmarshaling you want.

Comment: The output you see is the value returned by [this method](https://github.com/tooolbox/cybersource-rest-client-go/blob/master/client/payments/create_payment_responses.go#L67). This is because the `fmt` package automatically invokes the `Error() string` method on values whose types implement it. Just like it does with the `String() string` method. If you want to access some specific field nested inside `created` you should use the [selector expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors), e.g. `created.Payload.Links` or `created.Payload.ID`.

Comment: thanks mkopriva, it worked. I was not able to get the selected expression as you mentioned.